# Deducing private key in RSA encryption from public key, cyphertext and plain text

Tags: encryption, man-in-the-middle, rsa

Assuming someone is doing MITM attack. 
He knows the cyphertext, the public key and the plaintext message, can he deduce the private key from these 3 elements?

Comment: The whole point of strong encryption is that you cannot do that.

Comment: In asymmetric encryption an attacker has a much stronger attack: Knowing only the public key they can encrypt as many chosen plaintexts as they want. But even that is not enough to break properly implemented RSA.

Answer (score 0):

This attack is called [Known Plaintext Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack):

The known-plaintext attack (KPA) is an attack model for cryptanalysis where the attacker has access to both the plaintext (called a crib), and its encrypted version (ciphertext). These can be used to reveal further secret information such as secret keys and code books.

From the Wikipedia article:

> The KL-7, introduced in the mid-1950s, was the first U.S. cipher machine that was considered safe against known-plaintext attack.

It will work on ancient algorithms, but not on anything from 50 years ago or newer.

**Against RSA this will not work.** You can deduce a couple bits from the private key with enough time, changing the cyphertext, and using the endpoints as an oracle, but not some information a non-state agent would have much use.